# How can I display excel data with the .xlsx exstension in my windows application using data grid view?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, datagridview

I have an excel file that I would like to load into my form and display there. Is there any way to do this? Sorry I am fairly new at visual studio as well as visual basic. If anybody could help me out with this it would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options - all involve some additional library:

- [OpenXML 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free library from MS) can be used to read/modify the content of an .xlsx so you can display it anyway you want (for example in a data grid view)
- some (commercial) 3rd-party libraries come with grid controls allowing you to display excel files in your application (be it Winforms/WPF/ASP.NET...) like [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) etc.